# What exactly does the '2' mean when someone writes read(2) while specifying the system call?

Tags: c, operating-system

What does someone mean when they say read(2), or open(1)? What do the numbers in the brackets actually mean?

Edit:
Rephrased the title of the question.

Comment: I was with you until "brackets"...

Comment: They're man page *sections*. See: [What do the numbers in a man page mean?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bracket is used to specify the section of man pages. Man pages are organized into different sections and that section number specifies what type of "thing" it is. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page), a common organization of sections(on Research Unix, BSD, OS X and Linux) is like this:

```
1   General commands
2   System calls
3   Library functions, covering in particular the C standard library
4   Special files (usually devices, those found in /dev) and drivers
5   File formats and conventions
6   Games and screensavers
7   Miscellanea
8   System administration commands and daemons
```

For example, by `read(2)` it meant it is talking about OS system call `read`.

Answer (score 3):

They are the man page section identifiers. you should try

```
man 2 read
```

or

```
man 1 open
```

to see specific versions of those identifiers.